# Converting to Precomposed Unicode String using Python-AppKit-ObjectiveC

Tags: python, objective-c

This document by Apple [Technical Q&A QA1235](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2001/qa1235.html) describes a way to convert unicode strings from a composed to a decomposed version. Since I have a problem with  file names containing some characters (e.g. an accent grave), I'd like to try the conversion function

void CFStringNormalize(CFMutableStringRef theString,
                       CFStringNormalizationForm theForm);

I am using this with Python and the AppKit library. If i pass a Python String as an argument, I get:

> > > CoreFoundation.CFStringNormalize("abc",0)
> > >       2009-04-27 21:00:54.314 Python[4519:613] *** -[OC_PythonString _cfNormalize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f02510
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ValueError: NSInvalidArgumentException - *** -[OC_PythonString _cfNormalize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f02510

I suppose this is because a CFMutableStringRef is needed as an argument. How do I convert a Python String to CFMutableStringRef?

Comment: I don't know the calling convention for Python, but to get a mutable string from a regular string in Obj-C you would do: NSMutableString *foo = [theString mutableCopy]; To create an empty, mutable string, you could do: NSMutableString *foo = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; I would imagine you can do the same using the Python convention and just pass the reference to the CoreFoundation call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OC_PythonString (which is what Python strings are bridged to) is an NSString subclass, so you could get an NSMutableString with:

```
mutableString = NSMutableString.alloc().initWithString_("abc")
```

then use mutableString as the argument to CFStringNormalize.