# Precompose Unicode Character Sequences in Python

Tags: python, macos, unicode

How can I convert decomposed unicode character sequences like "LATIN SMALL LETTER E" + "COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT" (or U+0075 + U+0301) so they become the precomposed form: "LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE" (or U+00E9) using native Python 2.5+ functions?

If it matters, I am on Mac OS X (10.6.4) and I have seen the question [Converting to Precomposed Unicode String using Python-AppKit-ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794836/converting-to-precomposed-unicode-string-using-python-appkit-objectivec) but unfortunately while the described OS X native CoreFoundation function `CFStringNormalize` does not fail or halt the script execution it just doesn't do anything.
And by that I don't mean that it doesn't return anything (its return type is void - it mutates in place). I have also tried all possible values for the constant parameter that specifies precomposing or decomposing in either canonical or non-canonical forms.

That is why I am searching for a Python native method of handling this case.

Thank you very much for reading!

André

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446222/how-do-i-reverse-unicode-decomposition-using-python

Comment: Also thanks to you Kenny, for adding the cross-reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import unicodedata as ud

astr=u"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E}" + u"\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}"
combined_astr=ud.normalize('NFC',astr)
```

'NFC' tells [ud.normalize](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) to apply the canonical decomposition ('NFD'), then
compose pre-combined characters:

```
print(ud.name(combined_astr))
# LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
```

They both print the same:

```
print(astr)
# é
print(combined_astr)
# é
```

But their reprs are different:

```
print(repr(astr))
# u'e\u0301'
print(repr(combined_astr))
# u'\xe9'
```

And their encodings, in say `utf_8`, are (not surprisingly) different too:

```
print(repr(astr.encode('utf_8')))
# 'e\xcc\x81'
print(repr(combined_astr.encode('utf_8')))
# '\xc3\xa9'
```

Comment: From your repr examples this looks exactly like what I need. Thank you for taking the time to reply! Answer accepted.